Ошибка шифрования: StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found
h-ник сервера:
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QJsonValue>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QProcessEnvironment>
#include <aes.h>
#include <modes.h>
#include <base64.h>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

using namespace CryptoPP;


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    QString valid_login = "admin", valid_password = "admin";
    QJsonObject  read_param;
    QJsonDocument main_param_doc;
    QString std_path = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/standart_param.json";
    QJsonArray main_param;

private slots:
    void onClientConnected();
    void onClientDisconnected();
    void onClientReadData();

private:
    void dispatchCommand(QJsonObject& json_cmd,
                         QTextStream& client_stream);

    void command_getTime(QTextStream& client_stream);

    void command_getFormatTime(QJsonObject& json_cmd,
                               QTextStream& client_stream);
    void command_updateParam(QJsonObject& json_cmd, QTextStream& client_stream);
    void command_takeStdParam(QJsonObject& json_cmd, QTextStream& client_stream);
    void command_userAuth(QJsonObject& json_cmd, QTextStream& client_stream);
    void sendCommand(QJsonDocument& json_cmd,
                     QTextStream& client_stream);

    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTcpServer* m_tcpServer = nullptr;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H


cpp-шник сервера:
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QFile file(std_path);
    if (file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
        QByteArray qwerty = file.readAll();
        main_param_doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(qwerty);
        if (!main_param_doc.isNull() && !main_param_doc.isEmpty()) {
            QJsonObject tmp = main_param_doc.object();
            main_param = tmp.value("param").toArray();
            } else {
            QMessageBox::warning(0, "Ошибка", "JSON-Документ пуст",0,0);
        }
    }
    m_tcpServer = new QTcpServer(this);
    m_tcpServer->setProxy(QNetworkProxy::NoProxy);
    if (m_tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4, 5555))
        ui->statusBar->showMessage("Сервер запущен");
    else
        ui->statusBar->showMessage("Ошибка запуска сервера");
    connect(m_tcpServer, &QTcpServer::newConnection, this, &MainWindow::onClientConnected);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

std::string encrypt(const std::string& str_in, const std::string& key)
{
    std::string str_out;
    CryptoPP::ECB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption encryption((byte*)key.c_str(), key.length());

    CryptoPP::StringSource encryptor(str_in, true,
            new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(encryption,
                new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(
                    new CryptoPP::StringSink(str_out),
                    false
                )
            )
    );
    return str_out;
}

std::string decrypt(const std::string& str_in, const std::string& key)
{
    std::string str_out;

    CryptoPP::ECB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption decryption((byte*)key.c_str(), key.length());

    CryptoPP::StringSource decryptor(str_in, true,
        new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(
                new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(decryption,
                    new CryptoPP::StringSink(str_out)
                )
        )
    );
    return str_out;
}

void MainWindow::onClientConnected()
{
    QTcpSocket* clientConnection = m_tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
    connect(clientConnection, &QTcpSocket::disconnected, this, &MainWindow::onClientDisconnected);
    connect(clientConnection, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &MainWindow::onClientReadData);

//    QTextStream tcp_stream(clientConnection);
//    tcp_stream << "Hello" << flush;
    ui->listWidget->addItem("Подключился " + clientConnection->peerAddress().toString());
}

void MainWindow::onClientDisconnected()
{
    QTcpSocket* clientConnection = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
    if (clientConnection) {
        ui->listWidget->addItem("Отключился " + clientConnection->peerAddress().toString());
        clientConnection->deleteLater();
    }
}

void MainWindow::onClientReadData()
{
    QTcpSocket* clientConnection = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
    QTextStream tcp_stream(clientConnection);
    QString message = tcp_stream.readAll();
    QString temp = QString::fromStdString(decrypt(message.toStdString(),"1357924680753951"));


    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(temp.toUtf8());
    if (doc.isObject()) {
        QJsonObject obj = doc.object();
        if (obj.contains("command")) {
            dispatchCommand(obj, tcp_stream);
        }
        else
            ui->listWidget->addItem("Ошибка JSON");
    }
    else
        ui->listWidget->addItem("Ошибка JSON");
}

void MainWindow::dispatchCommand(QJsonObject &json_cmd,
                                 QTextStream &client_stream)
{
    QJsonValue val = json_cmd["command"];
    if (val.isString()) {
        QString cmd = val.toString();
        ui->listWidget->addItem("command: " + cmd);
        if (cmd == "getTime") {
            command_getTime(client_stream);
        }
        else if (cmd == "getFormatTime") {
            command_getFormatTime(json_cmd, client_stream);
        }
        else if (cmd == "updateParam") {
            command_updateParam(json_cmd, client_stream);
        }
        else if (cmd == "takeStdParam") {
            command_takeStdParam(json_cmd, client_stream);
        }
        else if (cmd == "userAuth") {
            command_userAuth(json_cmd, client_stream);
        }
        else
            ui->listWidget->addItem("Неизвестная команда");
    }
    else
        ui->listWidget->addItem("Ошибка JSON");
}

/*
 * { "answer": "getTme",
 *   "data": "16.05.2022 12:10:05" }
*/
void MainWindow::command_getTime(QTextStream &client_stream)
{
    QJsonDocument doc;
    QJsonObject answer;
    answer["answer"] = "getTime";
    answer["data"] = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString();
    doc.setObject(answer);
    sendCommand(doc, client_stream);
}

void MainWindow::command_getFormatTime(QJsonObject &json_cmd,
                                       QTextStream &client_stream)
{
    if (json_cmd.contains("params")) {
        QJsonValue val = json_cmd["params"];
        if (val.isObject()) {
            QJsonObject ob = val.toObject();
            if (ob.contains("timeFormat")) {
                QJsonValue fmt_val = ob["timeFormat"];
                if (fmt_val.isString()) {
                    QString tm_format = fmt_val.toString();
                    QJsonDocument doc;
                    QJsonObject answer;
                    answer["answer"] = "getFormatTime";
                    answer["data"] = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString(tm_format);
                    doc.setObject(answer);
                    sendCommand(doc, client_stream);
                }
                else
                    ui->listWidget->addItem("Ошибка JSON");
            }
            else
                ui->listWidget->addItem("Ошибка JSON");
        }
        else
            ui->listWidget->addItem("Ошибка JSON");
    }
    else
        ui->listWidget->addItem("Ошибка JSON");
}

void MainWindow::command_updateParam(QJsonObject& json_cmd, QTextStream& client_stream)
{
    QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
    QJsonArray temp_arr;
    QJsonObject temp_obj;
        for (const QString &key: env.keys()) {
            QJsonObject b;
            b[key] = env.value(key);
            temp_arr.append(b);
            }
        QJsonObject answer;
        answer["answer"] = "updateParam";
        answer["params"] = temp_arr;
        QJsonDocument doc;
        doc.setObject(answer);
        sendCommand(doc, client_stream);
}

void MainWindow::command_takeStdParam(QJsonObject& json_cmd, QTextStream &client_stream)
{
    QJsonObject answer;
    answer["answer"] = "takeStdParam";
    answer["result"] = main_param;
    QJsonDocument doc;
    doc.setObject(answer);
    sendCommand(doc, client_stream);
}

void MainWindow::command_userAuth(QJsonObject &json_cmd, QTextStream &client_stream)
{
    QJsonObject answer;
    if (json_cmd.value("password").toString() == valid_password && json_cmd.value("login").toString() == valid_login)
        answer["result"] = 1;
    else
        answer["result"] = 0;
    answer["answer"] = "userAuth";
    QJsonDocument doc;
    doc.setObject(answer);
    sendCommand(doc, client_stream);
}

void MainWindow::sendCommand(QJsonDocument &json_cmd,
                             QTextStream &client_stream)
{
    QString msg(json_cmd.toJson());
    ui->listWidget->addItem(msg);
    QString str = QString::fromStdString(encrypt(msg.toStdString(),"1357924680753951"));

    client_stream << str << flush;
}

h-ник клиента:
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QAuthenticator>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QJsonValue>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QAxObject>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <QSet>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <aes.h>
#include <modes.h>
#include <base64.h>


class Timer;
class AuthDialog;

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

using namespace CryptoPP;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    AuthDialog* authDialog_;
    void sendCommand(QJsonDocument &json_cmd);
    bool auth_status;
    QJsonObject list_param;
    QJsonDocument missmatches;
    QString json_path = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/missmatches.json";

private slots:
    void on_connectButton_clicked();

    void on_disconnectButton_clicked();

    void onServerConnected();
    void onServerDisconnected();
    void onServerReadData();
    void checkUser(QAuthenticator& tmp);

    void on_getTime_clicked();

    void on_getFormatTime_clicked();
    void updateParam();

    void on_compareButton_clicked();
    void exit_app();

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

private:
    void dispatchCommand(QJsonObject& json_cmd);
    void answer_getTime(QJsonObject& json_cmd);
    void answer_takeStdParam(QJsonObject& json_cmd);
    void answer_updateParam(QJsonObject& json_cmd);
    void answer_userAuth(QJsonObject& json_cmd);
    void change_status();


    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTimer *timer;
    QTcpSocket* m_serverConnection = nullptr;
    QTextStream m_tcpStream;
    QJsonArray StdParam, UpdParam;

signals:
    void success();
    void tryAgain();
};

class Timer : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
private slots:
};

class AuthDialog : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    int try_times = 5;
    AuthDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    QLineEdit *usernameEdit;
    QLineEdit *passwordEdit;
    void checkCredentials();
    void yspex();
    void neydacha();
    QPushButton *cancelButton, *okButton;


signals:
    void send(QAuthenticator& tmp);
    void changeAuthStatus();

private:
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

cpp-шник клиента:
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

AuthDialog::AuthDialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent) {
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    this->setFixedWidth(300);
    this->setFixedHeight(200);
    QLabel *usernameLabel = new QLabel("Логин:", this);
    AuthDialog::usernameEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
    layout->addWidget(usernameLabel);
    layout->addWidget(AuthDialog::usernameEdit);

    QLabel *passwordLabel = new QLabel("Пароль:", this);
    AuthDialog::passwordEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
    AuthDialog::passwordEdit->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
    layout->addWidget(passwordLabel);
    layout->addWidget(AuthDialog::passwordEdit);

    QPushButton *okButton = new QPushButton("Авторизация", this);
    layout->addWidget(okButton);

    connect(okButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &AuthDialog::checkCredentials);

    setWindowTitle("Окно авторизации");
    setModal(true);
    AuthDialog::show();
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(2);
    ui->tableWidget_2->setColumnCount(2);
    ui->statusbar->showMessage("Отключен");
    m_serverConnection = new QTcpSocket(this);
    m_serverConnection->setProxy(QNetworkProxy::NoProxy);
    m_tcpStream.setDevice(m_serverConnection);
    auth_status = false;
    connect(m_serverConnection, &QTcpSocket::connected, this, &MainWindow::onServerConnected);
    connect(m_serverConnection, &QTcpSocket::disconnected, this, &MainWindow::onServerDisconnected);
    connect(m_serverConnection, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &MainWindow::onServerReadData);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    m_serverConnection->abort();
    delete m_serverConnection;
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_connectButton_clicked()
{
    m_serverConnection->abort();
    m_serverConnection->connectToHost(ui->ipAddr->text(), ui->portNum->value());
}



void MainWindow::on_disconnectButton_clicked()
{
    m_serverConnection->close();
}

std::string encrypt(const std::string& str_in, const std::string& key)
{
    std::string str_out;
    CryptoPP::ECB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption encryption((byte*)key.c_str(), key.length());

    CryptoPP::StringSource encryptor(str_in, true,
            new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(encryption,
                new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(
                    new CryptoPP::StringSink(str_out),
                    false
                )
            )
    );
    return str_out;
}

std::string decrypt(const std::string& str_in, const std::string& key)
{
    std::string str_out;

    CryptoPP::ECB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption decryption((byte*)key.c_str(), key.length());

    CryptoPP::StringSource decryptor(str_in, true,
        new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(
                new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(decryption,
                    new CryptoPP::StringSink(str_out)
                )
        )
    );
    return str_out;
}



void MainWindow::onServerConnected()
{
    ui->statusbar->showMessage("Подключен");
    ui->connectButton->setEnabled(false);
    ui->disconnectButton->setEnabled(true);
    authDialog_ = new AuthDialog();
    connect(authDialog_, &AuthDialog::send, this, &MainWindow::checkUser);
    connect(this, &MainWindow::success, authDialog_, &AuthDialog::yspex);
    connect(this, &MainWindow::tryAgain, authDialog_, &AuthDialog::neydacha);
    connect(authDialog_, &AuthDialog::changeAuthStatus, this, &MainWindow::change_status);
    ui->centralwidget->setVisible(false);
    authDialog_->exec();
    if (auth_status == false)
        qApp->exit();
    ui->centralwidget->setVisible(true);
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::updateParam);
    timer->start(5000);
    QJsonObject cmd;
    QJsonDocument doc;
    cmd["command"] = "takeStdParam";
    doc.setObject(cmd);
    ui->getFormatTime->setEnabled(true);
    ui->getTime->setEnabled(true);
//    _sleep(4900);
    sendCommand(doc);
}

void MainWindow::onServerDisconnected()
{
    ui->statusbar->showMessage("Отключен");
    ui->connectButton->setEnabled(true);
    ui->disconnectButton->setEnabled(false);
    timer->stop();
    delete authDialog_;
}

void MainWindow::onServerReadData()
{
    QString message = m_tcpStream.readAll();
    try {
    QString rty = QString::fromStdString(decrypt(message.toStdString(),"1357924680753951"));
    ui->serverMessages->addItem(rty.trimmed());

    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(rty.toUtf8());
    if (doc.isObject()) {
        QJsonObject obj = doc.object();
        if (obj.contains("answer")) {
            dispatchCommand(obj);
        }
        else
            ui->serverMessages->addItem("Ошибка JSON");
    }
    else
        ui->serverMessages->addItem("Ошибка JSON");
    } catch (const CryptoPP::Exception &error)
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Ошибка", "Ошибка шифрования: " + QString(error.what()));
        ui->serverMessages->addItem("Ошибка шифрования: " + QString(error.what()));
    }
}

void MainWindow::checkUser(QAuthenticator &tmp)
{
    QJsonDocument doc;
    QJsonObject command;
    command["command"] = "userAuth";
    command["password"] = tmp.password();
    command["login"] = tmp.user();
    doc.setObject(command);
    sendCommand(doc);
}

/*
 * { "command": "getTime" }
*/
void MainWindow::on_getTime_clicked()
{
    QJsonDocument doc;
    QJsonObject command;
    command["command"] = "getTime";
    doc.setObject(command);
    sendCommand(doc);
}

void MainWindow::dispatchCommand(QJsonObject &json_cmd)
{
    QJsonValue val = json_cmd["answer"];
    if (val.isString()) {
        QString cmd = val.toString();
        ui->serverMessages->addItem("answer: " + cmd);
        if (cmd == "getTime") {
            // отправка текущего времени
            answer_getTime(json_cmd);
        }
        else if (cmd == "getFormatTime") {
            answer_getTime(json_cmd);
        }
        else if (cmd == "takeStdParam") {
            answer_takeStdParam(json_cmd);
        }
        else if (cmd == "updateParam") {
            answer_updateParam(json_cmd);
        }
        else if (cmd == "userAuth") {
            answer_userAuth(json_cmd);
        }
        else {
            ui->serverMessages->addItem("Неизвестная команда");
        }
    }
    else
        ui->serverMessages->addItem("Ошибка JSON");
}

void MainWindow::answer_getTime(QJsonObject &json_cmd)
{
    if (json_cmd.contains("data")) {
        QJsonValue val = json_cmd["data"];
        if (val.isString()) {
            QString time = val.toString();
            QMessageBox::information(this, "Время на сервере", time);
        }
        else
            ui->serverMessages->addItem("Ошибка JSON");
    }
    else
        ui->serverMessages->addItem("Ошибка JSON");
}

void MainWindow::answer_takeStdParam(QJsonObject &json_cmd)
{
    if (json_cmd.contains("result")) {
        QJsonValue val = json_cmd.value("result");
        if (val.isArray()) {
            StdParam = val.toArray();
            ui->serverMessages->addItem("эталонные параметры получены успешно");
            int n = StdParam.size();
            ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(n);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                QJsonObject r = StdParam.at(i).toObject();
                QString key = r.keys().at(0);
                QString values = r.value(key).toString();
                ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(key));
                ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(values));
            }
        }
        else
            ui->serverMessages->addItem("Ошибка JSON");
    }
    else
        ui->serverMessages->addItem("Ошибка JSON");
}

void MainWindow::answer_updateParam(QJsonObject &json_cmd)
{
    if (json_cmd.contains("params"))
    {
        QJsonValue val = json_cmd.value("params");
        UpdParam = val.toArray();
        int n = UpdParam.size();
        ui->tableWidget_2->setRowCount(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            QJsonObject r = UpdParam.at(i).toObject();
            QString key = r.keys().at(0);
            QString values = r.value(key).toString();
            ui->tableWidget_2->setItem(i, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(key));
            ui->tableWidget_2->setItem(i, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(values));
        }
    }
    ui->tableWidget_2->resizeColumnsToContents();
    ui->compareButton->setEnabled(true);
    ui->pushButton_2->setEnabled(true);
}

void MainWindow::answer_userAuth(QJsonObject &json_cmd)
{
    if (json_cmd.value("result") == 1)
        success();
    else
        tryAgain();
}

void MainWindow::change_status()
{
    auth_status = true;
}

void MainWindow::sendCommand(QJsonDocument &json_cmd)
{
    QString msg(json_cmd.toJson());
    ui->serverMessages->addItem(msg);
    if (m_serverConnection->isWritable()){
        QString rty = QString::fromStdString(encrypt(msg.toStdString(),"1357924680753951"));
        m_tcpStream << rty << flush;
    }
}
/*
 * { "command": "getFormatTime",
 *   "params": {
 *          "timeFormat": "hh:mm:ss"
 *    }
 * }
*/
void MainWindow::on_getFormatTime_clicked()
{
    QJsonDocument doc;
    QJsonObject command;
    command["command"] = "getFormatTime";
    QJsonObject params;
    params["timeFormat"] = ui->timeFormat->text();
    command["params"] = params;
    doc.setObject(command);
    sendCommand(doc);
}

/*
 * { "command": "updateParam"
 * }
*/


void MainWindow::updateParam()
{
    QJsonObject command;
    QJsonDocument doc;
    command["command"] = "updateParam";
    doc.setObject(command);
    sendCommand(doc);
}

QStringList find_mismatches(const QJsonArray& std_arr, const QJsonArray& upd_arr) {
    QStringList miss;
    QSet<QString> std_keys_set, upd_keys_set, temp;
    for (auto tmp : std_arr) {
        QJsonObject temp = tmp.toObject();
        QString key = temp.keys().at(0);
        std_keys_set.insert(key);
    }
    for (auto tmp : upd_arr) {
        QJsonObject temp = tmp.toObject();
        QString key = temp.keys().at(0);
        upd_keys_set.insert(key);
    }
    temp = std_keys_set;
    temp.subtract(upd_keys_set);
    miss.append(temp.toList());
    temp = upd_keys_set;
    temp.subtract(std_keys_set);
    miss.append(temp.toList());
    return miss;
}

void MainWindow::on_compareButton_clicked()
{
    QStringList final;
    QAxObject *word = new QAxObject("Word.Application", this);
    QAxObject *documents = word->querySubObject("Documents");
    QAxObject *myDocuments = documents->querySubObject("Add()");
    QAxObject *range = myDocuments->querySubObject("Range()");
    QMap<QString, QString> std_map, upd_map;
       for (auto temp : StdParam) {
           QJsonObject obj = temp.toObject();
           QString key = obj.keys().first();
           QString val = obj.value(key).toString();
           std_map[key] = val;
       }
       for (auto temp : UpdParam) {
           QJsonObject obj = temp.toObject();
           QString key = obj.keys().first();
           QString val = obj.value(key).toString();
           upd_map[key] = val;
       }
       for (auto key : std_map.keys()) {
           if (upd_map.contains(key)) {
               if (std_map[key]!= upd_map[key])
                   final.append("Найдено несоответствие: значение переменной под именем " + key + " было изменено\n");
           }
       }
    QStringList mismatches = find_mismatches(StdParam, UpdParam);
    for(auto tmp: mismatches)
    {
        final.append("Найдено несоответствие: переменная под именем '" + tmp + "' была добавлена/удалена \n");
    }
    if (!list_param.value("root").toObject().contains(ui->ipAddr->text())){
        QString tmp;
        for (QString line: final) {
            line.resize(line.size() - 2);
            tmp.append(line + ";");
            }
        QJsonObject miss, times, comp;
        QJsonArray temp_arr, final_arr;
        times["times"] = final.size();
        miss["mismatches"] = tmp;
        temp_arr.append(times);
        temp_arr.append(miss);
        comp[ui->ipAddr->text()] = temp_arr;
        final_arr.append(comp);
        list_param.insert("root", final_arr);
    }
    QJsonDocument temp_doc(list_param);
    QFile file(json_path);
    if (file.open(QFile::Append)) {
        file.write(temp_doc.toJson());
        file.close();
    }
        for (QString line: final) {
                range->dynamicCall("InsertAfter(Text)", line);
                line.resize(line.size() - 2);
                QString str = line;
            }
        QString str = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, "Выберите файл для сохранения отчёта", "", "*");
        myDocuments->dynamicCall("SaveAs(Text)", str);
        myDocuments->dynamicCall("Close()");
        word->dynamicCall("Quit()");
        ui->pushButton->setEnabled(true);
}

void MainWindow::exit_app()
{
    this->destroy();
}

void AuthDialog::checkCredentials()
{
    QAuthenticator authenticator;
    authenticator.setUser(usernameEdit->text());
    authenticator.setPassword(passwordEdit->text());
    if (authenticator.user() == "")
        QMessageBox::warning(0, "Ошибка авторизации", "Введите логин");
    if (authenticator.password() == "")
        QMessageBox::warning(0, "Ошибка авторизации", "Введите пароль");
    if (authenticator.user() != "" && authenticator.password() != "")
    {
    send(authenticator);
    }
}

void AuthDialog::yspex()
{
    QMessageBox::information(0, "Успех", "Вход выполнен");
    changeAuthStatus();
    accept();
}

void AuthDialog::neydacha()
{
    try_times--;
    QString end_of_message;
    if (try_times == 5)
        end_of_message = " попыток";
    if (try_times < 5 && try_times > 1)
        end_of_message = " попытки";
    if (try_times == 1)
        end_of_message = " попытка";
    if (try_times != 0) {
    QMessageBox::warning(0, "Ошибка авторизации", "Логин или пароль не совпадают.\n Осталось " + QString::number(try_times) + end_of_message);
    }
    if (try_times == 0){
        QMessageBox::critical(0, "Отказано в доступе", "Превышено количество попыток входа");
        qApp->exit();
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QFile file(json_path);
    QJsonObject zxc;
    QJsonArray json_arr;
    QJsonDocument json_doc;
    if (file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
        QByteArray qwerty = file.readAll();
        json_doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(qwerty);
        QJsonObject tmp = json_doc.object();
        json_arr = tmp.value("root").toArray();
    }
    int max = json_arr.at(0).toObject().value("times").toInt();
    QString ans = json_arr.at(0).toObject().begin().key();
    for (auto temp: json_arr)
    {
        QJsonObject jobj = temp.toObject();
        if (jobj.value("times").toInt() > max)
        {
            max = jobj.value("times").toInt();
            ans = jobj.begin().key();
        }
    }
    QMessageBox::information(0, "Результат", "ip-адрес клмпьютера с наибольшим количеством несоответствий:\n" + ans);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    bool flag = false;
    for (auto temp : UpdParam)
    {
        QJsonObject obj = temp.toObject();
        if (obj.begin().key() == ui->lineEdit->text())
        {
            QMessageBox::information(0, "Результат", "переменная под именем " + ui->lineEdit->text() + " со значением " + obj.value(ui->lineEdit->text()).toString() + " была найдена среди текущих переменных");
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    if (flag == false)
        QMessageBox::information(0, "Результат", "переменная под именем " + ui->lineEdit->text() + " не найдена среди текущих переменных");
    flag = false;
    for (auto temp : StdParam)
    {
        QJsonObject obj = temp.toObject();
        if (obj.begin().key() == ui->lineEdit->text())
        {
            QMessageBox::information(0, "Результат", "переменная под именем " + ui->lineEdit->text() + " со значением " + obj.value(ui->lineEdit->text()).toString() + " была найдена среди эталонных переменных");
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    if (flag == false)
        QMessageBox::information(0, "Результат", "переменная под именем " + ui->lineEdit->text() + " не найдена среди эталонных переменных");
}

Я начинающий программист и время от времени код работает не совсем корректно, выдавая различные ошибки. Например, ошибка, которая возникает всегда - после 3-4 нажатий на кнопки "Время на сервере" и "Время в формате" возникает ошибка Ошибка шифрования: StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found. Помогите, пожалуйста, скорректировать код таким образом, чтобы он стал более стабильным. Скрин формы клиента прилагаю.
